# Force Users to disable Siri if on the organization network

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Folks,

We have an iOS app that does some functionality similar to Siri. This is for in app navigation. The problem is, it is an health care app and the hospitals don't want the users to accidentally start dictating to Siri because of HIPAA regulation. So if they are on hospital network, is there a way we can enforce our provisioning profile to make the user turn off Siri.

Thanks!

Comment: iOS 6 has single-app mode.  I don't know if that disables SIRI, though.

Answer (score 4):

Yep: you can install a configuration profile that disables Siri, among many other things. Check out the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/), specifically its [Restriction settings](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-ipcu/#app665501b0).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew that I could put some restrictions but I don't want to put the restriction entirely. The restriction should happen only when the user is on the secure network either directly or through VPN.

Comment: In that case, no. Configuration profiles aren’t that flexible.